# How to get a UIBarButtonSystemItem on a UIToolBar to take me to another view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Accept my early apologies as totally new to this so my terminology may not be accurate, hope you can understand what it is that i'm asking.

I am having issues getting a UIBarButtonSystemItem to take me back to a different view when pushed.  I have defined a UIToolBar with a UIBarButtonSystemItem on it which compiles and works perfectly.  However, when the button is pushed the app crashes.

This is the code i have used to define the UIToolBar and UIButton:

```
//create toolbar using new
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[toolbar sizeToFit];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50);

//Add buttons
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(pressButton1:)];
```

I have then added flexitem to this and added the button to the array using the following code:

```
//Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                     target:nil
                     action:nil];

//Add buttons to the array
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, flexItem, nil];
```

This is where I fall down and I have attempted to get the button to take me to a previous view when pushed by using the following code:

```
-(void)pressButton1:(id)sender {
    BMR_TDEE_CalculatorViewController *controller1 = [[BMR_TDEE_CalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BMR_TDEE_ViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
    [controller1 release];
}
```

Like I said, this just crashes my simulator.  It compiles without issue but Im guessing the code is fundamentally wrong as i am new to this.  Any help explained dumbed down would be fantastic ;-)

Thanks All

Comment: Could you show us the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(pressButton1:)
```

should be:

```
UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] init];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 32);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

For the `(void)pressbutton` code it should now be:

```
-(IBAction)pressButton1:(id)sender {
    BMR_TDEE_CalculatorViewController *controller = [[BMR_TDEE_CalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BMR_TDEE_CalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info, and the edits....but nothing has seemed to change the behaviour.